# Indoor localization application with beacons

Tags: beacon, distriqt

Can I create an indoor localization application with this beacon extension? 
I didn't see anything in the documentation related to range between the phone and a beacon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

The accuracy value on a BeaconObject is the estimated range from the device to the beacon in meters.